# NSDate from NSString in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdate

One simple thing on conversion from `NSString` to `NSDate`. How can I convert  `Mon, 27 August 2012 01:30 AM` to `NSDate` in this same format. I tried with `NSDateFormatter`. But I am not getting it in this required format. Can anyone help? This is what I tried.

```
 NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEEE,dd MM yyyy HH:mm a"];
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"Mon,27 August 2012 01:30 AM"];
NSLog(@"%@",date1);
```

Comment: Working with default format?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NSDateFormatter** is to specify the format that will appear in the date-string when extracting **string from date** or the format that is in the date-string when extracting **date from string**

So whenever you extract NSDate from a NSString, NSDate is always obtained in default date format(eg **2012-08-27 00:30:00 +0000**)... only the when you extract NSString from NSDate, NSString can be obtained in desired(custom) format that you set in NSDateFormatter.

Comment: i need to add this date to calendar event.Thats why i am trying like this.

Comment: if you want it as NSDate object then there is default format as i mentioned above... if you want it in your custom format then you have to store it in NSString object

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you sure!

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformater=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
[dateformater setDateFormat:@"EEEE,dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm a"];

NSDate *todayTmp=[NSDate date];
NSString *conversionDate=[dateformater stringFromDate:todayTmp];

Note : (Upper case) HH for 24h time format, (Lower case) hh for 12h time format
```

Comment: i have to convert to date from string

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *myDateAsAStringValue = @"Mon, 27 August 2012 01:30 AM";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a"];

NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];

myDate = [df dateFromString:myDateAsAStringValue];

[df release];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"%@", strDate);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

please use below code

```
   NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [df setDateFormat:@"EEE,dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a"];
   NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"Mon,27 August 2012 01:30 AM"];
   NSLog(@"%@",date1);
```

your formatter is wrong
check this one

Comment: This works as long as you use an english locale. It fails for everyone else.

Comment: this is what i am getting in the log "2012-08-26 20:00:00 +0000"

Comment: ya, it shows "2012-08-26 20:00:00 +0000" because "Mon,27 August 2012 01:30 AM" is IST time and nsdate shows GMT time.                        IST time = GMT + 5:30 hr  so when IST time is 1:30 AM and date is 27 then GMT time is 8:00 PM and date is 26.

Answer (score 0):

NSLog will return NSDate in a fixed format, i guess. 
If we need Date in different format, we should have to format it via NSDateFormatter and get it as NSString. 
Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set the correct locale! If your device does not use an english locale NSDateFormatter can have problems to convert `Mon` and `August` into useful information because Mon is not the correct abbreviation for Monday in your language. For example in Germany the correct three letter abbreviation for Monday is `Mon.`.

If you parse dates that have words in it you have to set the correct locale.

This should work:

```
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE,dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a"];

NSLocale *posixLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[df setLocale:posixLocale];

NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"Mon,27 August 2012 01:30 AM"];
NSLog(@"%@",date1);
```

EEE is the dateformatter code for a three letter weekday abbreviation.
hh is the dateformatter code for Hours between 1 and 12. HH means 0-23
MMMM is the full month, MM would be the numeric value (= 08) of the month.